# Share aspx page between projects

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, reference, share, web-deployment

We have a solution with multiple web projects, and there are some pages that should be present in several of them. So we'd need some sort of a shared project which contains aspx files, and which can be referenced by other web projects.

Now there are a few implementations out there:

One implementation [described by ScottGu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/08/28/423888.aspx) which involves building the shared project, and than copying the output aspx into the host project, and referencing the dll of the aspx. This method has the disadvantage that if the apsx gets modified it must been recopied.

Another option, based on [David Ebbo's post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2005/10/31/turning-an-ascx-user-control-into-a-redistributable-custom-control.aspx) would be to convert the aspx into ascx-es which can be referenced as custom controls, and than include those custom-control-aspx-es into the host project inside of some placeholder pages. But my concerns are: can all apsx pages transformed into an ascx? I mean there's no Page.LoadComplete event in user controls for example.

And yet another option is to use virtual directories that map into the shared webproject, as described in a Microsoft [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/825996). The problem again with this method is that the shared aspx-es must be in predefined directories(that is the virtual directory).
If the name of virtual directory overlaps a physical directory, the virtual overrides it and no pages from the latter can be used.
Is it perhaps possible to merge these two together?

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance
P.S. How about debugging the shared pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this problem by making shared Class Library that contains .ascx controls. Have not found real difficulties when converting from .aspx pages to .ascx controls. Found this sample by ScottGu really simple and good place to start. http://webproject.scottgu.com/CSharp/usercontrols/usercontrols.aspx.

Comment: And with UserControls there is no need to copy them around(see the 2nd paragraph proposal from the question). Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Now I'm just copying these dll on PreBuild event, which isn't so big problem. I should take a look at David Ebbo's post. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

The solution which we are using is [ScottGu's method](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/08/28/423888.aspx), which involves copying the aspx files from the shared project to the host projects.

A post build event in the shared project copies the files to their place, like this

```
xcopy "$(ProjectDir)Forms\Techs\AddEditTech.aspx" "$(SolutionDir)..\TTAdmin\Forms\Companies"  /i /d /y
if errorlevel 1 goto BuildEventFailed

xcopy    ....

goto BuildEventOK

:BuildEventFailed
echo POSTBUILDSTEP for $(ProjectName) FAILED
exit 1

:BuildEventOK
echo POSTBUILDSTEP for $(ProjectName) COMPLETED OK
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about baseclassing the functionality into classes that inherit from Page and place those classes in the shared DLL.  All implementing applications could then implement that page by inheriting from it and still be able to change functionality assuming the base classes provide overridable methods.  I've had pretty good success with this when I had a lot of pages that were used in many applications and all had the same code.  Just a possibility.

Comment: Good point, but I have some content on the aspx-es (controls and static content). Is there an easy way to compile that content into the dll? I've tried to compile the complete page (markup+code) into the dll(by precompiling it) and inherting from that class, but than there's a runtime error, "An error occurred while try to load the string resources" which makes me think that the page tries to load the markup from the dll as a resource.

Comment: Should be able to compile the content into the dll by setting the build property of all controls to embedded resource.  You might have to load the controls from code by querying the Assembly's resources, but it should work out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered service oriented development?  Build the functionality into services you can share.  Build your functionality like widgets.  This way you only have one codebase but you can use it in multiple sites.

Think outside the (.Net box)