# Common ASPX pages used by multiple Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, design-patterns, architecture

Have a number of applications, which have similar pages.
E.g Payment Page, Search Page etc.

Looking for the best way to design the application so all the applications can use the common pages rather than having 3 versions of the same file.

It was suggested creating an app containing the common pages only where the other apps would transfer to when accessing the webpage and out again when finished. This just seems wrong, or am I incorrect.

Any advise appreciated.

ASPNET, c# framework 4.0

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to [override](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910441/en-us) virtual path provider, which doesn't seem to be a trivial task..

Also there is a similar question - [Share aspx page between projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420299/share-aspx-page-between-projects) (suggests to reuse at user controls level).